# Error return from the MODISSummaries function (R package MODISTools)

Tags: r, matrix, error-handling

Does anyone know how to handle this error? It occurs both on my PC ("Windows" "7 x64" "build 7601, Service Pack 1" "x86-64") and Mac ("Darwin" "Darwin" "12.5.0" "Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64")

```
library(MODISTools)

data(SubsetExample)

MODISSubsets(LoadDat = SubsetExample, Products = "MOD13Q1", Bands = c("250m_16_days_EVI",
                             "250m_16_days_pixel_reliability"), Size = c(0,0), StartDate = TRUE)

MODISSummaries(LoadDat = SubsetExample, Product = "MOD13Q1", Bands = "250m_16_days_EVI",
                               ValidRange = c(-2000,10000), NoDataFill = -3000, ScaleFactor = 0.0001,
                               StartDate = TRUE, QualityScreen = TRUE, QualityThreshold = 0,
                               QualityBand = "250m_16_days_pixel_reliability")
```

**Error:**

```
Error in matrix(band.data.site$mean.band[band.data.site$ID == lat.long$SubsetID[i]],  : 
  non-numeric matrix extent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for highlighting this bug. I've pushed a fix to my GitHub repository (https://github.com/seantuck12/MODISTools/). I will update the version on CRAN as soon as possible but in the meantime please use the GitHub version.